# return empty array although table is empty

Tags: php, mysql

How can I echo empty array to frontend although the table doesn't have any records?

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM person");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $row = array(
        'fname' => $res['fname']
    );

    $encoded[] = $row;
}

//$encoded ? echo json_encode($encoded); : echo array();
```

Comment: What do you mean by echo empty array to frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize an empty `array` at the beginning of your code:

```
$encoded = array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM person");

while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $encoded[] = array('fname' => $res['fname']);
}

echo json_encode($encoded);
```

If no results have been found, this will outout `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following above the loop:

```
$encoded = array();
```

Comment: Had a typo in it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to *echo an empty array* would be to echo a pair of square brackets:

```
echo "[]";
```

---

In your case, if you have initialised the `$encoded` array somewhere above the code you have provided and if it's not not tampered with by other code, you can simply encode it:

**Example:**

```
# Initialise an array.
$encoded = [];

# Execute the query.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM person");

# Loop.
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
    $encoded[]= ["fname" => $res['fname']];
}

# Echo the the array (empty or not).
echo json_encode($encoded);
```